How to create a floating window with Jetpack Compose
I just started learning kotlin with Compose and I want to create an app that stands out from other apps. I already know that I need to create a service, but I don't know how.
Something like

I tried this example  but didn't understand anything, and I don't have the libraries. The other examples I read don't use Compose.
